# integer to string itox function in C

Tags: c, string-conversion

I got this from somewhere but i don't kind of understand the meaning behind it. 
How does this actually works?

```
void itox(unsigned int i, char *s) 
{ 
    unsigned char n; 

    s += 4; 
    *s = '\0'; 

    for (n = 4; n != 0; --n) { 
        *--s = "0123456789ABCDEF"[i & 0x0F]; 
        i >>= 4; 
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What part do you not understand? If you don't understand _anything_ in this code, it's time to start reading your C text book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry for not stating it clear, I don't really understand the command inside the for loop.

Comment: The string `"0123456789ABCDEF"` is a 16 char array and you extract the char at position `i & 0x0F` (ie, the number given by the 4 LSB of i).

Comment: You could use a tool like https://www.onlinegdb.com/ to debug and understand what happens there

Comment: I don't know if the code is yours.You should always check if a pointer is NULL before you dereference it.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis, not necessarily. If the function spec. says that s needs to point to valid memory, no need to check. And even if you check and s is NULL what do you do?

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation it help me greatly.

Comment: @Tsakiroglou Fotis I don't really think that's true. Some would say the caller should know if it's null or not to save on precious cpu cycles, imo it would be better to assert and crash the program if s is null.

Comment: @Jabberwocky If you check if the null you return an error code.You might be right however I strongly believe that a piece of code has to be secure.You can't let someone to cause a segfault either by accident or not.In the organization I work for, this wouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis but would it be acceptable to pass a NULL pointer to the function in first place?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Oh of course if your intention is to let a window for a later ddos attack.

Comment: @Jabberwocky But I understand what you mean.And you are right as well.

Comment: The same for @George

Answer (score 4):

It assumes that `s` is a buffer of length 5 (including the null terminator) and writes the hex representation of `i` there. The result is the hex representation of `i` modulo 65536 (for lots of old systems, `unsigned int` has a range of `0` to `65535`).

```
s += 4; 
*s = '\0';
```

This goes to the end of `s` and puts a null terminator there.

`for (n = 4; n != 0; --n) {`

Now we loop backwards through the result string and fill in the appropriate `char`.

```
"0123456789ABCDEF"[i & 0x0F];
```

This selects the correct `char`. `i & 0x0F` gets the least significant hex value and by using that as a subscript for array access on `"0123456789ABCDEF"`, the respective char is obtained.

```
*--s = ...
```

The char that is obtained is put in the correct place and the pointer is decreased again so the next position can be filled in the next run through the loop.

```
i >>= 4;
```

We now shift the number by four bits, removing the four bits we just converted into a hex digit. Now the next four bits will be the least significant hex digit.

---

**Example**

let's take the number `58008`. In hex it is `0xE298`. Mod 16 it is `8`, so `"0123456789ABCDEF"[8];` gets `"8"`.

Then we shift it four bits, resulting in `3625`. Mod 16 that's `9`, and we get the `"9"`. After the next shift we get `226`, which mod 16 is `2`, and one shift later we get `14`. `"0123456789ABCDEF"[14]` is `"E"`.

Assemble those results backwards and you get `E298`.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part here is

```
*--s = "0123456789ABCDEF"[i & 0x0F];
```

Here `"0123456789ABCDEF"` is a string literal which is stored in the compiler memory.

We are accessing this literal as an array. So, `"0123456789ABCDEF"[0]` will be the character `'0'` and `"0123456789ABCDEF"[1]` will be `'1'`

With that information, we can easily analyse the entire code.

```
s += 4;      //Increment pointer s by 4
*s = '\0';   // last value to be '\0' to end the string


for (n = 4; n != 0; --n) { 
    *--s = "0123456789ABCDEF"[i & 0x0F];   
    i >>= 4; 
} 

// say i is 0x231
// For n == 4, i & 0x0F will be 1, 
// *--s will point s to the third element in the array, and
// this will be assigned to 1.
// i <<4 will be i/16, so i will be 0x23

// for n == 3, 
// *--s will point to second element of array, which will be 3.

// and so on.
```

Finally what you get is the hexadecimal value of the integer in `s`

Comment: _which is stored in the compiler memory_: this is not quite correct